# Java: how to save all the words from a text file on a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, cpu-word, counter

I am trying to write a code that reads a file and puts all the words on a String array and then it prints all the array as a column. I wrote a code that should work but instead of getting the words printed, I get only "null" all the time.

The problem must be on the: `word[totalWords] = read.inWord();`

What do you recommend me to write instead, to get the words correctly stored?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    In read = new In (args[0]);

    int totalWords = 0;

    String word[] = new String[31000];
    int uniqueWords[] = new int[31000];

    while(read.endOfFile() == false) {

        word[totalWords] = read.inWord();
        totalWords++;
        System.out.println(word[totalWords]);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this supposed to be `System.out.println(word[totalWords-1]);`

Comment: If you assume the problem must be at `word[totalWords] = read.inWord();`, then that's a good spot to set a breakpoint, run your program, and look at the value of `word[totalWords]` as well as the value of `totalWords` both on this line and on your print line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the element at the index after the one you've modified which hasn't been initialized yet, ie. is `null`. Flip your logic

```
word[totalWords] = read.inWord();
System.out.println(word[totalWords]);
totalWords++;
```

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(word[totalWords++]);`  But +1 either way.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the word a bit late. 
It should be:

```
word[totalWords] = read.inWord();
System.out.println(word[totalWords]);
totalWords++;
```

i.e. you should first print the word and then increment the counter. In your case you are trying to print the value of the unassigned array element, hence you get `null`.

More beautiful way would be :

```
 word[totalWords] = read.inWord();
 System.out.println(word[totalWords++]);
```

Comment: but if you do it the beautiful way, the day you remove your `println` the code stops working.